# MobileFirst - Answering a call to a WS (JAX-RS)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have a java adapter (JAX-RS) that returns a **POJO**, one of the attributes is called `validateUser` and is a `boolean` value. I want to get the value of this boolean when called from `main.js`

It should work like this (main.js):

```
onGetLoginSuccess function (response)
busy.hide ();
alert ("validate:" + response ["validateUser"]);
```

As I can get the value in the variable response, the `validateUser` attribute my POJO.

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 3):

You can use alert(response.responseJSON.validateUser);

In general to examine the structure of "response" you could do something like: alert(JSON.stringify(response)); It could help you to understand which fields are available and how can you find this validateUser.

It is also important to make sure that your JAX-RS adapter returns JSON content type. Make sure that you have the annotation: @Produces("applicaion/json") in your JAX-RS method that returns this POJO

Comment: Great! Can you accept the answer so that I will get the credit? Thanks!